# I keep getting errors that "navigation" is not defined

Tags: react-native, expo, stack-navigator

I am trying to create a login button that navigates to another page but I keep getting errors that "navigation" is not defined

here's the screenshot of the error:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QvvO.jpg)

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPDwC.jpg)
that's the app component:

```
export default function App({navigation}) {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
     <Image
        
        source={logo}
        style={styles.stretch}
      />
      <Image
        
        source={logo2}
        style={styles.stretch2}
      />
      
  
  <Button title="Login" style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton,styles.top]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
   </Button>  
   <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer2, styles.loginButton2,styles.top2]} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText2}>Register</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>  
        <NavigationContainer>
          
  <Stack.Navigator >
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
</NavigationContainer>
        </View>
    
  );
}
```

here I got stuck after using the navigation Ref method:
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56FZX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your App component is a React hook, so calling `this.props` won't work. You can just use `navigation` from your App's params.
2. The navigation prop is only available to components wrapped within your `<NavigationContainer>` component. You'll probably still get an error trying to call `navigate` from the `App` component since `<NavigationContainer>` is a child of it.

Your best bet is to only use the `navigation` prop on components within a `<NavigationContainer>` or accessing it like this based on the documentation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop

EDIT:
If you want to access navigation outside of the navigation container, you'll need a ref pointing to it.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App({}) {
    const navigationRef = useRef(null)

    // Then wherever you wanna call navigate you do this:
    // () => navigationRef.current.navigate("Details")
    // make sure you do a null check on navigationRef.current if you want to be extra safe

    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        ....
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: I already tried this and resulted error in the second screenshot

Comment: Yup, checkout point 2. You're accessing navigation from your App component, when the NavigationContainer that provides that prop is a child of it.

Comment: If you console.log the navigation prop of App, you'll see that it is undefined.

Comment: so if I want to add navigation what can I do?

Comment: Updating answer, one sec

Comment: well where should this line "() => navigationRef.current.navigate("Details")"be placed?

Comment: In your login button's onPress

Comment: Updated answer, make sure you import it when you import React

Comment: I still get error navigation not defined because it is above the navigationRef line so I will update the question with a screenshot

Comment: Okay updated answer. Don't access navigation from App.js, it will always be undefined, use the navigationRef

Answer (score 2):

there is no `this.props` in function components:

```
export default function App({navigation}) {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

this should be

```
export default function App({navigation}) {
  const { navigate } = navigation;
```

notice that you already destructured navigation from props in the function signature

Comment: will attach a screenshot to the post now